# How to plot a line plot over sns.heatmap over the center of tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science, data-visualization

Currently, I am trying to plot the viterbi path over all state probabilities. Basically, it is a line plot over a Seaborn heatmap I am using the following code

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = sns.heatmap(plot.T, cmap="viridis")
ax.set_title("State probabilities")
ax.set_xlabel("Time step")
ax.set_ylabel("Hidden states")
plt.plot(viterbi_path, color='red')
plt.show()
```

And I am getting something like this:
[image: What I have]

While the line to start from the center and with no transitions rather on actual values like in this image
[image: Image of What I need]

How can I achieve this?

Thank you for the help :)

A basic reproducible toy code for experiment

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 15)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
t = np.arange(10)
t = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9]
plt.plot(t)
plt.show()
```

[image: Generates this heatmap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seaborn draws the ticks at the half positions (`0.5, 1.5, ...`). You can add a half to have the lines at the centers in the y-direction.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 15)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
t = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
plt.plot(np.array(t) + 0.5, color='lime', lw=3)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap with lines]

You can do the same to also center in the x-direction:

```py
plt.plot(np.arange(len(t)) + 0.5, np.array(t) + 0.5, color='lime', lw=3)
```

[image: sns.heatmap with lines centered in x and y]

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for, just to add on Is there any way to make the transitions stepwise instead of this slope?

Comment: Matplotlib has a step function. `plt.step(...)`

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/step_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-step-demo-py

Comment: Thanks! That did the job, adding `plt.step(..., where='mid')`